# Decrypt AES 256 bit ciphertext with key

Tags: openssl

```
Exercise 3.8 Familiarize yourself with a cryptographic software development
package for your computer. A popular open source package is OpenSSL,
though there are numerous other alternatives.
Using an existing cryptography library, decrypt the following ciphertext (in
hex)
53 9B 33 3B 39 70 6D 14 90 28 CF E1 D9 D4 A4 07
with the following 256-bit key (also in hex)
80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
using AES.
```

So I looked up the openssl man page and got this so far:

```
openssl enc -d -aes256 -K 8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 -in ciphertext.txt -out plaintext.txt -iv 0
```

I have stored the HEX ciphertext as binary into the textfile ciphertext.
I'm not sure why I need to initialize a IV at all. But this gives me a bad decrypt error.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSL defaults (mostly) to CBC, so `-aes256` is really `-aes-256-cbc`, which needs an IV. Specify `-aes-256-ecb` instead, which doesn't. (If you haven't learned about block cipher modes yet, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation .) In addition the data here appears not to be padded, although it happens to sort-of work; better to specify `-nopad`. With those I get:

```
$ od -tx1 su1670756
0000000 53 9b 33 3b 39 70 6d 14 90 28 cf e1 d9 d4 a4 07
0000020
$ echo $K
8000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
$ openssl <su1670756 enc -aes-256-ecb -d -K $K -nopad | od -tx1
0000000 80 70 60 50 40 30 20 10 08 07 06 05 04 03 02 01
0000020
```